# Importação do Kivy pelo terminal não funciona, mas no IDLE importa normalmente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tive bastante dificuldade pra instalar o kivy e colocar ele funcionando no Ubuntu. Mas agora eu não consigo fazer o kivy funcionar no modo interativo diretamente pelo terminal, mas consigo fazer isso pelo IDLE.

Alguém consegue me ajudar a resolver isso? Não sei por que motivo isso ocorre.

Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você instalaou o kivy?

Comment: Eu tentei instalar com PPA, com o PIP, com um arquivo tar.gz que peguei do próprio site, em todos tive problema. Ai eu instalei uma versão especifica do python, a 3.5.2, e começou a funcionar, mas logo depois parou.

Comment: Ele pergeu o caminho da biblioteca pelo jeito. Fiz um  sys.path.insert(0,'/diretorio-da-biblioteca') e ele voltou a funcionar na seção que eu tinha usado, mas preciso fazer isso permanentemente pra ele sempre ter o caminho.

Comment: Alias... Parou de funcionar no próprio IDLE assim que eu fechei ele e abri de novo.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, ja tentou reinstalar/instalar o kivy passando a versão do python que esta usando?!
Abaixo algumas tentativas possíveis, também pode encontrar um help em https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy

sudo apt-get install python3-kivy

pip install kivy
```

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso. Não desinstalei nada, só coloquei pra instalar novamente. Não adiantou.